# Prove that $\int f(\theta(x))\delta(x)dx = \int f(y)dy$ ??

Tags: real-analysis, dirac-delta

Show that the above is true. where $\delta(x)$ is the delta and $\theta(x)$ is the Heaviside Step function. We know that 
$$\frac{d\theta(x)}{dx} = \delta(x)$$

I am stuck on this.
Please help me?
Thanks

Comment: 1. Learn mathJax, 2. What have you tried 3.where do you get stuck?

Comment: Funny, if $f=1$, this yields $1=+\infty$, no?

Answer (score 2):

Even for very nice choices of $f$, I fail to see how this is meaningful beyond a nice symbolic "equality" via u-substitution as per Daniel Littlewood's answer. The reason being that $f\circ \theta$ is in most instances not well-defined as a test function at $0$ so integration against $\delta$ is ill-defined. (The one exception being $f\equiv 0$.)

Taking $f(x) = \exp(-x^2)$ for instance (arguably one of the nicest functions in many senses of the word), the integral on the right hand side is $\sqrt{\pi}$. The integral on the left hand side should pick out the value of $f\circ\theta$ at $0$, however at $0$, $f\circ\theta$ has a jump discontinuity so the Dirac delta averages the left and right hand limits of $f\circ\theta$. These limits evaluate to $(f\circ\theta)(0^-) = f(0) = 1$ and $(f\circ\theta)(0^+) = f(1) = e^{-1}$. Their average is definitively not $\sqrt{\pi}$.

Comment: But $f\circ\theta$ is in fact continuous at $0$ if $f$ is continuous, because $f\circ\theta(x) = f(x)$ if $x\ge 0$, and $=f(0)$ if $x<0$. Right?

Comment: @JackLee No. $(f\circ\theta)(x) = f(1)$ for $x>0$.

Comment: Aargh. Just being stupid. Thanks.

Comment: @JackLee No worries. I almost did the same thing in my answer. Weird how that got both of us.

Answer (score 1):

It would be hard to give a proof, since writing things like $\frac{d\theta}{dx}=\delta$ already puts you on dubious logical ground. In any case, if we assume that then your integral is just $$\int dx \theta'(x)f(\theta(x)) = \int dyf(y)$$
just by making the substitution $y=\theta(x)$.

Comment: Even for very nice choices of $f$, I fail to see how this is meaningful beyond a nice symbolic "equality" via u-substitution. The reason being that $f\circ \theta$ is in most instances not well-defined as a test function at $0$. (The one exception being $f\equiv 0$.)

Comment: I agree. I'm not sure who gave the OP this question, but this is certainly the combination of symbols they want to receive back.

Answer (score 1):

It is useful to review the subsitution theorem which tells us what constitutes a valid subsitution:

> Let $\phi$ be a real function which has a derivative on the closed interval $[a,b]$. Let $I$ be an open interval which contains the image of $[a,b]$ under $\phi$. Let $f$ be a real function which is continuous on $I$. **Then** 
>   $$\int_a^b f(\phi(t))\phi'(t)\,{\rm d}t = \int_{\phi(a)}^{\phi(b)}f(u)\,{\rm d}u$$

The function $\theta(t)$ you are trying to substitute does not have a derivative at $x=0$ and the image of $\theta(t)$ under $\mathbb{R}$ is two single points!

We can however apply substitution by $\theta$ on any interval that does not contain $0$ to get

$$\int_a^b f(\theta(t))\cdot 0\,{\rm d}t = \int_{0}^{0}f(u)\,{\rm d}u$$

or

$$\int_a^b f(\theta(t))\cdot 0\,{\rm d}t = \int_{1}^{1}f(u)\,{\rm d}u$$

which both are trivially true.